# Как записать символы \ и " в регулярное выражение php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, text

Есть некий текст, в котором некоторые слова завёрнуты в комбинацию символов \". например Sample text \"Username\" lorem ipsum. Хочу с помощью регулярного выражения избавиться от этих противных \", но не могу правильно их внести в паттерн. Пробовал и через кодировку этих символов и просто писать, но ничего не выходит, подскажите как выбрать эти символы в регулярном выражении.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример кода, который не работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ваша строка

```
$str = 'Sample text \"Username\" lorem ipsum';
```

регулярное выражение так

```
echo(preg_replace('/\\\"/',"",$str));
```

или так

```
echo(preg_replace("/\\\\\"/","",$str));
```

Answer (score 4):

В вашем случае регулярки не нужны. Достаточно функции [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

Например, заменяем комбинацию `\"` на кавычки `"`

```
$str = 'Sample text \"Username\" lorem ipsum';
$str = str_replace('\"', '"', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Результат

```
string 'Sample text "Username" lorem ipsum' (length=34)
```

или полностью удаляем такую комбинацию

```
$str = 'Sample text \"Username\" lorem ipsum';
$str = str_replace('\"', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Результат

```
string 'Sample text Username lorem ipsum' (length=32)
```